# flexbox - holy grail popup within a holy grail page

Tags: html, css, flexbox, popup

After finally getting the "Holy Grail" layout working properly yesterday in my main page... I sought to embed a "Holy Grail" inside a popup without much success.  I am having two core problems.

1) The Popup-holy grail will not take up 100% height, despite the parent having a defined height.

2) This probably applies to all popups, but if I set my popup to 100% width and 100% height then attempt to apply padding to it... it merely shifts the popup to the right, but does not take into account the proper width.  This is annoying... I found this hack of using translate: (-50%, -50%).. but it isn't quite the same... I'd like to be able to set a margin/padding of 32px on my popup and have it work (like a sane person assume it would work).  The code below demonstrates the issue.  The popup version of the holy grail will not extend to the bottom and, if you try to set margins, it doesn't behave as a sane person would expect.

I want to get this working because, essentially, every page I'd ever want to make would be a variation of this, plus or minus different parts.  If I can do this, then I should be able to do anything with layout, in theory.

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.flexcolumncontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flexrowcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.absolutepositioned {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00ffff;
  color: black;
}

.layout__body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.layout__content {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.layout__columns {
  flex: 0 0 12em;
}

.layout__nav {
  order: -1;
  position: relative;
}

.layout__aside {
  position: relative;
}


/*assign this style to a flex item to fix STUUUPID positioning problems with relative positions*/


/*you can set style="somestyle someotherstyle flexfixpos"*/

.fixflex {
  position: relative;
}

.layout__content {
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
}

.layout__columns {
  background: green;
}

header,
footer {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

footer a {
  flex: 1;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
}

body.fillbrowser,
html.fillbrowser {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

.popup {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  padding: 32px 32px 32px 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<![p]template="none" />
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HolyGrail.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
        body, html {
          height: 100%;
          margin: 0;
          font-family: Helvetica;
        }
    </style>
      <header>
        <h1>FLEXBOX LAYOUT PROOF OF CONCEPT</h1>
      </header>
      <div class="layout__body">
        <main class="layout__content">
            <div class="absolutepositioned">For the body</div>
            <div style="color: #00FFFF;"><b>absolute positioned stuff</b></div>
        </main>
        <nav class="layout__nav layout__columns">
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            NAV ITEMS<br>
            <div class="absolutepositioned">For the NaV</div>
        </nav>
        <aside class="layout__aside layout__columns">YOUR VIAGRA ADS HERE
            <div class="absolutepositioned">absolute right bar</div>
        </aside>
      </div>
      <footer> <div class="absolutepositioned">FOOTER</div>
      </footer>
        <div class="popup">
            <div class="fillpopup">
                <div class="flexcontainer">
                  <header>
                    <h1>THIS IS A POP-UP THAT IS ALSO FLEX BUT SHOULD TAKE UP ENTIRE HEIGHT</h1>
                  </header>
                  <div class="layout__body">
                    <main class="layout__content">
                        <div class="absolutepositioned">For the body</div>
                        <div style="color: #00FFFF;"><b>the blue box should be here</b></div>
                    </main>
                    <nav class="layout__nav layout__columns">
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        NAV ITEMS<br>
                        <div class="absolutepositioned">For the NaV</div>
                    </nav>
                    <aside class="layout__aside layout__columns">YOUR VIAGRA ADS HERE
                    <div class="absolutepositioned">absolute right bar</div>
                    </aside>
                  </div>
                  <footer> <div class="absolutepositioned">FOOTER</div>
                  </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you can make a jsfiddle or something it'll be easier to help you, but as a starting point, [check out this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp) and also if you're wanting the popup to be sized based on the viewport, perhaps just use `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh` instead of percentages.

Comment: I've put it on JS fiddle, but it hasn't appeared as public yet

Comment: I think the answer to this is DON'T use flexbox.... use grid instead.  Redo from scratch... attempt #3.  I have it working with grids... a completely different approach .... CSS is an annoying hodgepodge of garbage.

Comment: Well... i tried  using GRID but... grid had unwanted caveats as well.  I can't get the body to scroll when inside a pop-up .... CSS is soooooo laaaaame.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm understanding you correctly, which I'm not sure I am, you want a popup over your page layout that will fill the viewport and scroll if the content gets too long?

If that's right then perhaps something like this will get you started:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;  
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.wrapper > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 1 100%;
}

.header {
  background: tomato;
}

.footer {
  background: lightgreen;
}

.main,
.aside {
  min-height: calc( 100vh - 100px );
}

.main {
  background: deepskyblue;
}

.aside-1 {
  background: gold;
}

.aside-2 {
  background: hotpink;
}

.popup {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
  .aside { flex: 1 0; }
}

@media all and (min-width: 800px) {
  .main    { flex: 3 0px; }
  .aside-1 { order: 1; } 
  .main    { order: 2; }
  .aside-2 { order: 3; }
  .footer  { order: 4; }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="whatever.css" />
</head>

<body>

<!-- Bottom layer -->
<div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">
        Header
    </header>

    <article class="main">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
    </article>

    <aside class="aside aside-1">
        Aside 1
    </aside>

    <aside class="aside aside-2">
        Aside 2
    </aside>

    <footer class="footer">
        Footer
    </footer>

</div>
 
<!-- Popup -->
<div class="wrapper popup">

    <header class="header">
        Popup Header
    </header>

    <article class="main">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>  
    </article>

    <aside class="aside aside-1">
        Popup Aside 1
    </aside>

    <aside class="aside aside-2">
        Popup Aside 2
    </aside>

    <footer class="footer">
        Popup Footer
    </footer>

</div>
 
</body>

</html>
```

This is based on the example by Chris Coyier on [this page](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), so the design is responsive as well. All I did was apply `position: fixed` to the popup, attach it to all sides of the viewport, and set `overflow: auto`. If you're wanting to use `position: absolute` then you can still use `bottom: 0, top: 0, left: 0, right: 0` to stretch it to fill its container.

If you want fixed heights for the header and footer you could do this (as I used in the example above):

```
.main, aside {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried out your answer yet... I've been able to accomplish FULL SCREEN takeovers, but I have not been able to get the popup to obey it's container size when formatted with any kind of holy-grail solution (including grids).  The browser gets confused and seems to take use body dimensions as the container dimensions.  Thank you for your answer... I will test it out.